# InvalidKeyException: invalid key format in Java using RSA Keys

Tags: java, web-applications, rsa

I generated a public using java keygenerator:

> Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits   modulus:
>   106394877608018766537720801416655991345106535990850729605963854419450103716730599362154190537257597233014065015311499176359112816419965961469419756050290964343366687334245741905264407605904082573446954295309549250335299907317631410981650257400135070254491184426528002396792285738067623733919575203674519111607
>   public exponent: 65537

I sent this key from client side(via copy,paste) and received exactly exactly the same as a string. Then I tried to reconstruct it:

```
byte [] bytes = publicKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
Key key = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(bytes));
```

Then I am returning from the function.
I am getting `Invalid Key Exception` from line 2 where I form Key.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to Use RSAPublicKeySpec

```
String modulus="106394877608018766537720801416655991345106535990850729605963854419450103716730599362154190537257597233014065015311499176359112816419965961469419756050290964343366687334245741905264407605904082573446954295309549250335299907317631410981650257400135070254491184426528002396792285738067623733919575203674519111607";
    RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(modulus),BigInteger.valueOf(65537));

    Key key = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(spec);
```